# rails how to run system command from rails command securely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have an ActiveJob which triggers a system script to run:

```
 `grunt custom-job --src=files --dest="file" --vars='#{user_input_vars_from_json}'`
```

Point being is that

```
user_input_vars_from_json
```

Is a json config which comes as user input parameter from a controller.
I do validate the json format but how can I ensure that there is no harmful code send to my system command?

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to preface this with: Any user input should be treated as dangerous.  I would not recommend executing any command using user-provided inputs.

The first thing you're going to want to do is lock down the input as much as possible.  Consider restricting the length of the `user_input_vars_from_json` to prevent buffer overflow and DoS attacks. I also recommend trying to figure out a way to both validate and restrict the "vars" you are trying to set in the `user_input_vars_from_json` JSON to filter out any unwanted keys/values.

Once your input is cleaned, you can use [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) in combination with [Shellwords](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) to get as close to safe as possible in executing your command from your job:

```
require 'shellwords'
system("grunt", "custom-job", "--src=files", '--dest="file"', "--vars=\"#{Shellwords.escape(user_input_vars_from_json)}\""
```